# jQuery read only <div>

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using mvc razor.

I want to make all input in `<div>` "read only" if they do not have permission at the load of view.

```
if(!myUser.Permissions("View infor"))
    $('div.divMemberLookup :input').readonly(true);
```

I'm trying to use jQuery readonly plugin.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I just can not put it togather

Comment: Do you really have to use the readonly plugin or is it ok to use plain jquery?

Answer (score 1):

if you want read only (as opposed to disabled)  you can do this

$('div input').attr("readonly", "readonly");

one of the differences is that you can select and copy readonly attributes but not disabled ones.

Answer (score 0):

trie this:

```
$('div input').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I have try this if(!myUser.Permissions("View infor")) $('div input').attr("disabled", true); but nothing happend there are few more div on the views   how to make it load on page load

Answer (score 0):

Does this really need a plugin? Can you not just do something like this:

```
if(!myUser.Permissions("View infor"))
    $('div.divMemberLookup input').attr('disabled',true);
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Toukakoukan/rjmNy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

add the `@` sign in front of your if statement.

```
@if(!myUser.Permissions("View infor"))
{

 $('div.divMemberLookup :input').attr('readonly',true);

}
```

That way it will only render that JS if the serverside permissions are true.

Comment: it says too many character in character literal    any thought why it giving me this error

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to generate the input field from the server side code:

In ur Razor page, you have this

```
@RAW(Model.printInputfield());
```

on ur Model class you have a method to genarate the input field

```
public string printInputfield(){
    if(!myUser.Permissions("View infor"))
       return "<input type='text' disabled:disabled value="ur Values" />";
     else
       return "<input type='text' value="ur Values"  />";
}
```

Comment: does this will make all input field read only in specific div

Comment: I like kind of code in controller but not sure how to do that